# Propel model build problems

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I'm having problems using `propel model:build`. I've tried the steps on [Propelorm.org - Documentation: Configuration](http://propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html).

But I keep getting the following error:

```
[Propel\Generator\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
  Invalid database name: no configured connection named `default`.
```

My `propel.json` file (tried other formats too) looks like this:

```
{
        "propel": {
                "database": {
                        "connections": {
                                "redactedname": {
                                        "adapter": "mysql",
                                        "classname": "Propel\\Runtime\\Connection\\ConnectionWrapper",
                                        "dsn": "mysql:host=localhost;database=redactedname;dbname=redactedname",
                                        "user": "redactedname",
                                        "password": "redactedpassword",
                                        "attributes": []
                                }
                        }
                },
                "runtime": {
                        "defaultConnection": "redactedname",
                        "connections":  ["redactedname"]
                },
                "generator": {
                        "defaultConnection": "redactedname",
                        "connections": ["redactedname"]
                }
        }
}
```

It seems as though Propel is trying to load an entry named 'default' going from looking at some PHP code on the Propel repo but I can't seem to find out why it's not using my config file. The `--config-dir="/my/redacted/path"` directive doesn't do anything either.

I'm new to Propel and I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong. with some of the other config file formats I sometimes get an empty 'generated-classes' folder and no errors.

The schema.xml I'm using was generated by propel by reverse engineering a MySQL database and seems valid.

Comment: Are you using version 2? I believe it should work, but it's still in alpha, and progress on getting it stable has been very slow of late. I am sticking to 1.7.x, even though development has largely ceased there.

Comment: i am; i just followed the documentation which recommends using composer with "~2.0@dev" should i use a different one?

Comment: Well, it's a matter of opinion. I suspect the dev team would say stick to what you have - you're on version 2. Since what you are doing ought to be pretty simple, I expect this should work! Not tried this branch though.

Comment: Ah, what would be the name for one of the stable branches for composer?. is there a list?

Comment: There isn't a stable branch for version 2, all the [alphas are here](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/releases). Stable branches for [version 1 are here](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/releases). If you want to continue with version 2, then you're on the right tag already (and you should probably persist for a bit, IMO, before switching to the previous major version).

Comment: Are you able to run any other commands?  The errors seems to be a DB connection issue, but if other commands are working then the DB connections is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my friends noticed that it was related to 'schema.xml';

the database was listed as 'default' there which i had to rename to the name of the connection in 'propel.json'. I was under assumption that propel would use 'defaultConnection' in the 'propel.json' file but that doesn't seem to be the case.

It's all working now.

Comment: also don't forget to use "propel config:convert" to generate a php config file for use in your application, since propel doesn't use the 'propel.json' file for that..